# Disable a complete bar in highcharts when clicking on its label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph:

[image]

Location 1 is getting pretty big, which making it hard to read Location 2 data. How can I make a function to click on Location X to hide its bar?

For example, I click on Location 1 and its bar gets hidden and the label gets a gray out color, while the remaining locations data get re-ordered for a better view. When clicking on the gray out Location again it is shown again.

It should work like the label statuses but then per location.

Look at this basic example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4mh5qa4/). I've managed to make the labels clickable to do something.

This is the code I've added to the bottom of the javascript:

```
chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label)
{
    label.style.cursor = "pointer";
  label.onclick = function(){
    alert('You clicked on '+this.textContent);
  }
});
```

But how can I build on this to hide the entire relative bar and change the color of the label, and when click again, show the bar again?

---

**EDIT**

I'm sorry that I've made this discovery so late.

The graph is not created directly with JavaScript and the highchart library. It is created with a PHP Symfony Bundle so this is the action that creates the chart:

```
public function chartAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data = $em->getRepository(Order::class)
        ->getOrdersByStatusAndLocation();

    $statuses = [];
    $locations = [];
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if (!in_array($row['name'], $locations)) {
            $locations[] = $row['name'];
        }

        $statuses[$row['status']][$row['name']] = [
            'y' => $row['number_of_orders'],
            'url' => $this->generateUrl(
                'order_list',
                ['filter' => [
                    'location' => ['type' => null, 'value' => $row['id']],
                    'status' => ['type' => null, 'value' => $row['status']],
                ]]
            )
        ];
    }

    $result = [];
    foreach ($statuses as $status => $value) {
        $row = [
            'name' => $status,
            'data' => array_fill(0, count($locations), 0)
        ];

        foreach ($value as $location => $numOfOrders) {
            $row['data'][array_search($location, $locations)] = $numOfOrders;
        }

        $result[] = $row;
    }

    $plotOptions = [
        'stacking' => 'normal',
        'cursor' => 'pointer',
        'point' => [
            'events' => [
                'click' => new Expr("function () {
                    location.href = this.url;
                }")
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $chart = new Highchart();
    $chart->chart->renderTo('locationOrderChart');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart
    $chart->chart->type('bar');
    $chart->plotOptions->series($plotOptions);
    $chart->title->text('Orders per location');
    $chart->xAxis->title(['text'  => 'location']);
    $chart->xAxis->categories($locations);
    $chart->yAxis->title(['text'  => 'Orders']);
    $chart->yAxis->allowDecimals(false);
    $chart->series($result);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Dashboard:chart_location_order_status.html.twig', [
        'chart' => $chart,
    ]);
}
```

Is there a way to implement the answer below into the code above to get the results like Patata's fiddle in the comment of the answer?

I'll really appreciate it if I can get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Update with verifiable example

Answer (score 1):

I tried a solution, not so decent but it'll do your job:

```js
var origCategories = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
var user1 = [5, 3, 4, 7, 2];
var user2 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 1];
var user3 = [3, 4, 4, 2, 5];
var filteredCategories = [...origCategories];
var filteredUser1 = [...user1],
  filteredUser2 = [...user2],
  filteredUser3 = [...user3];

var data = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: filteredCategories,
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: filteredUser1
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: filteredUser2
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: filteredUser3
  }]
}
generateChart = () => {
    chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label) {
        label.style.cursor = "pointer";
        label.onclick = function() {
          let index = origCategories.indexOf(this.textContent);
          filteredUser1[index] = 0;
          filteredUser2[index] = 0;
          filteredUser3[index] = 0;
          chart.destroy();
          chart = Highcharts.chart('container', data);
          generateChart();
        }
      });
}
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', data);
generateChart();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

You can also check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4mh5qa4/1/)

Comment: Hey I forked your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o6L6apuL/. It is much closer what OP wants. Thanks

Comment: @Patata That is beautiful! That is exactly what I want. I came across a new problem. The chart I'm working with is not done with JavaScript like your answer, but a PHP Symfony bundle is used to make it with PHP and then the bundle renders it to JavaScript. I've updated my answer.